# (Angular2 Meteor) fetch from collection return empty in ngOnInit, but not for all collections

Tags: angular, meteor, angular-meteor

[edit:]Hello everyone, after few days without finding any solutions and either receiving answers on this post, I try again with editing this post, cheer.

Usually, I found solutions myself but this time something weird is getting me crazy day after day..

Here's the thing : (Using Meteor and Angular2)

I have 2 different collections, documents and fieldList, defined the same way:

*in /both/collections/documents.collection.ts*

```
export const Docs = new Mongo.Collection<Doc>('documents');
export const Docss = MongoObservable.fromExisting(Docs);
```

*in /both/collections/fieldList.collection.ts*

```
export const fieldLists = new Mongo.Collection<FieldList>('fieldList');
export const fieldListss = MongoObservable.fromExisting(fieldLists);
```

Also published the same way:

*in /server/imports/publications/documents.ts*

```
Meteor.publish('docsList', () => {
    return Docs.find({},{});
});
```

*in /server/imports/publications/fieldList.ts*

```
Meteor.publish('fieldListList', () => {
    return fieldLists.find({},{});
});
```

Now, in my component, I subscribe:

```
...import skipped...
export class documentPanelDocFormComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy{
...Var declaration skipped...
...Constructor declaration skipped...
ngOnInit() {
        this.fieldListSub = MeteorObservable.subscribe('fieldListList').subscribe();
        this.docsSub = MeteorObservable.subscribe('docsList').subscribe();
...
```

And it's working as, now, I can see in mongol both collections:

[Mongol result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFWgl.jpg)

Unfortunately, when I fetch from db :

```
....still inside ngOnInit...
console.log("Documents Fetch:",Docss.find({}).fetch());
console.log("FieldLists Fetch:",fieldListss.find({}).fetch());
```

It works, but only for documents, and i get an empty array for fieldList:

[Result in chrome web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJzQJ.jpg)

If anyone knows what's wrong here please enlighten me :)
thanks in advance and sorry for bad english
PS: if you need any other part of the code let me know

Comment: Hello everyone,
Find that data were not available yet for fieldList in ngOnInit ( still couldn't understand why it is available for Docss..) and used callbacks in MeteorObservable subscribe like this:
`[...]
.subscribe(docId => {this.docId = docId;
                this.fieldListSub = MeteorObservable.subscribe('fieldListList').subscribe(
                    () => {
                        this.docsSub = MeteorObservable.subscribe('docsList').subscribe(
                            () => { console.log("FieldLists Fetch:",fieldListss.find({}).fetch());}`

Answer (score 0):

The collections are not ready to be used until the subscribe block has resolved. As you have said in your comment, if you embed the find in the function of the subscribe, the subscription is ready and the find will work correctly.

Any find call on a collection before the subscription is ready will result in it returning nothing.

What you are experiencing when one fetch works and the other doesn’t is basically luck. The first subscription had resolved so the first fetch returned correctly. The second subscription was not ready so the second fetch failed.

This is purely down to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. I think you are assuming that the .subscribe will wait until it is ready before executing the next line of code. It doesn’t work like this